# Numpy combining advanced and basic indexing does not result in the shape I expected

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
np_zero = np.zeros(shape=(5,5,5,5,10))

### (1)
np_zero[1,:,1,1,[1,2,3]].shape # -> (3,5)
# What I expect -> (5,3)
```

**Problem:**

I must be wrong but as far as my understanding on indexing, above code should give (5,3) as shape
(because the second and the last index selects more than one elements in each dimension, so the shape order also must be len(second), len(the fifth)

However below code produces in the order I expect.

```
np_zero[:,1,1,1,[1,2,3]].shape # -> (5,3)
np_zero[:,1,1,1,[1,2,3]].shape # -> (5,3)

### (2)
np_zero[1,:,1,1,:].shape # -> (5,10), the last index changed from [1,2,3] -> :
```

The only difference between (1) and (2) are one index is : and the other is [1,2,3]

Please let me know what I am missing!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you read the "Combining advanced and basic indexing" section in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html?

Comment: `np_zero[:,1,1,1,[1,2,3]]` you would get *5 rows with 3 zeros in each*, `np_zero[1,:,1,1,:]` -> you would get *5 rows with all the elements i.e. 10 zeros in each*

Comment: @Julien, I read it but didnt understand 100% of them... Can you let me know which part I should read it to understand the mentioned problem?

Comment: @Ch3steR Yes, but my questions is why np_zero[1,:,1,1,[1,2,3]] gives 3 rows with all the elements i.e 5 zeros in each

Comment: When the slice is in the middle, its dimension (here 5) gets tacked on to the end.  The 3 comes from the advanced indexing, and comes first.

Answer (score 0):

To better understanding, you should use:

- a lower dimension (3 is sufficient)
- `np.arange` instead `np.zero`

Example:

`a = np.arange(3*3*5).reshape((3,3,5))`

Gives you:

```
[                         # dim-3d <- the 1st index [3d,  :,  :]
  [                       # dim-2d <- the 2nd index [ :, 2d:  :]
    [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4], # dim-1d <- the 3rd index [ :,  :, 1d]
    [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
    [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
  ],
  [
    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
  ],
  [
    [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
    [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
    [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
  ]
]
```

`:` means "the whole xxx" (cell, line, column in 3D)

```
# Get 38 -> third cell (3 - 1), second line (2 - 1), fourth column (4 - 1)
>>> a[2, 1, 3]
38

# Get the (whole) second line of third cell
>>> a[2, 1, :]
array([35, 36, 37, 38, 39])

# Get the (whole) fourth column of each cell
>>> a[:, :, 3]
array([[ 3,  8, 13],
       [18, 23, 28],
       [33, 38, 43]])
# note the dim reduction (3d -> 2d) and the transposition (columns to rows)

# (1) Get the (whole) first line of each cell
>>> a[:, 0, :]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]])

# (2) Same as above but just get the second, third and fourth columns (index: 1, 2, 3)
>>> a[:, 0, [1,2,3]]
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [16, 17, 18],
       [31, 32, 33]])
```

You can see the difference between (1) and (2). In the first case, you select the whole line (all columns) so the shape is (3, 5) while in the second case, you select a subset of the row so the shape is (3, 3).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using the correct terms (cell / block, line / row). Feel free to correct them!

Comment: Your examples omit the OP's puzzling case, the one with a list index, and a slice in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

The mixed basic and advanced indexing section explains that when the slice is in the middle of some advanced indexings, its dimension gets appended to the end:

```
Out[22]: array([[1., 2., 3., 7.]])
In [23]: 
In [23]: np_zero = np.zeros(shape=(5,5,5,5,10))
    ...: 
    ...: ### (1)
    ...: np_zero[1,:,1,1,[1,2,3]].shape
Out[23]: (3, 5)
```

A way around this is to index twice, so the slice is first in the 2nd:

```
In [24]: np_zero[1][:,1,1,[1,2,3]].shape
Out[24]: (5, 3)
```

The docs explain that with a mixed indexing there's an ambiguity issue.  That is more obvious when doing something like

```
np_zero[[1,2,3],:,[4,5,6]]
```

where the 2 lists index a size 3 block; should that be first or last?  In your example only one index is a list, the rest scalars.  There shouldn't be an ambiguity.  But apparently coding details make it hard to treat this as a special case.  This issue has been known and discussed for quite some time.